# Compare folders

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to compare 2 folder structures:

Source structure

```
$SrcFolders

C:\Temp\FolderName\FolderA
C:\Temp\FolderName\FolderB\SubFolderBA
C:\Temp\FolderName\FolderB\SubFolderBB
C:\Temp\FolderName\FolderC
```

Target structure

```
$TrgFolders

S:\Docs\FolderName\FolderA
S:\Docs\FolderName\FolderB\SomethingWrong
S:\Docs\FolderName\FolderB\SubFolderBA
S:\Docs\FolderName\FolderB\SubFolderBB
S:\Docs\FolderName\FolderB\SubFolderBB\SomethingWrong
S:\Docs\FolderName\FolderC
S:\Docs\FolderName\SomethingWrong
```

I'm trying to find the best possible match:

- When the target folder and the source folder are the same, that's the one
- In case they're not the same, the longest matching one from the source is needed

**The code**

```
$Source = 'C:\Temp\FolderName\'
$Target = 'S:\Docs\FolderName'

foreach ($t in ($TrgFolders.FullName)) {
    $Folder = $t.Replace($Target,$Source)

    # Exact match
    # 'S:\Docs\FolderName\FolderA' > Desired result: 'C:\Temp\FolderName\FolderA'
    if ($SrcFolders.FullName -contains $Folder) {
        $FileACL = Get-Acl ($Folder + '\' + $TempFile)
        break
    }

    # Next best match
    # 'S:\Docs\FolderName\FolderB\SomethingWrong' > Desired result: 'C:\Temp\FolderName\FolderB' 
    # 'S:\Docs\FolderName\FolderB\SubFolderBB\SomethingWrong' > Desired result: 'C:\Temp\FolderName\FolderB\SubFolderBB'
    $F = $SrcFolders.FullName | where {$_ -like "$Folder*"} | sort length | select -First 1
    $FileACL = Get-Acl ($F + '\' + $TempFile)

}
```

As you can see finding the exact match is easy with `-contains` but finding the next best match is not really working.. Thank you for your help.

Comment: In the example source and target structure you provided, everything in source is present in the target. But you also talk about "best match" for which you have no example. What qualifies as a match and what makes such a match the best match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I've solved my own issue:

```
foreach ($t in ($TrgFolders.FullName)) {
    $SrcFolder = $t.Replace($Target,$Source)
    $Split = $SrcFolder.Split('\')

    for ($i=1; $i -lt $Split.count; $i++) {

        $R = $Split[0..($Split.Count-$i)] -join '\'

        if ($SrcFolders.FullName -contains $R) {
            $FileACL = Get-Acl ($R + '\' + $TempFile)
            break
        }
    }
}
```